# VM to be domain join via automation script

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Exact error : VM has reported a error when processing the extension (publisher Microsoft /compute and type json addDomain extenntion and error message is 'Exception occurred while domain join 'abc-eu' in azure devops pipeline i am getting this error using biceps :
This issue occurred due to vm should exist in the same subnet of the  domain controller. What is the alternate solution for this to do via automation

Comment: Could you please provide additional details about the connectivity between the Domain Controller and the VM? How do they communicate? Same subnet? Peering? VPN Site to Site? At first it seems that the VM cannot reach the Domain Controller but it might be something else

Comment: Initially i used to create a vm and manually i was adding vm to the domain join, but when i am trying the same with Automation script via biceps i got this issue.
Private ip was created for subnet and is used for communication

Comment: So, this VM has connectivity to the Domain Controller because it works if you manually add, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. what may be reason for domain join error ? Any idea

Comment: Can you please share the error screenshot in the question? And the Bicep that you are trying to use? 

Here is an example to have a VM to join a domain with Bicep https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vm-domain-join/main.bicep

Comment: Please review the tags you choose more carefully. You tagged this question with several incorrect or unrelated topics.